# Cannot apply permission for Google-managed SSL certificates to service account

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

When I try to create a managed certficate through a service account I get the error

> managedcertificates.networking.gke.io "..." is forbidden: User "..." cannot get resource "managedcertificates" in API group "networking.gke.io"
>   ... Required "container.managedCertificates.get" permission.

I tried to add the `container.managedCertificates.get` permission to the service account with a custom role, but there are no "container.managedCertificates.*"-permissions available at all which I could select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also tried in my project to reproduce the scenario, yes I am not having permissions "container.managedCertificates.*"- available when trying to add to a custom role. As the document [1](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#container.developer),  permission container.managedCertificates* is not listed that we could add.

Please note that as Managed Certificates is in beta [2](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/managed-certs), seems Google Product Engineers are working on this.

However adding the role Kubernetes Engine Admin to the service account does solve the issue.[3](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#kubernetes-engine-roles) Permissions are container.* , resourcemanager.projects.get , resourcemanager.projects.list .

Answer (score 0):

You could follow up the Public Issue Tracker [1](https://issuetracker.google.com/145935180). This kind of investigation takes time. You will be able to receive any updates or status of this issue here [1](https://issuetracker.google.com/145935180). As the engineering team working on the issue, send any updates or question to them writing in the link [1](https://issuetracker.google.com/145935180).

You could have the link [2](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe) about how to subscribe or star any issue to know further update in the issuetracker.